# Page navigation within the controller

Tags: wicket

What is the method to do page navigation within a Wicket "controller"?  I would like to go to another internal page and pass in parameters based on data within the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a good page navigation method:

```
public void onSubmit() {
        PageParameters params = new PageParameters();
        params.add("param1", "value1");
        setResponsePage(ListContacts.class, params);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not just a good method, that is THE method of displaying a bookmarkable page.

If you want to display a non-bookmarkable page (or a bookmarkable page in a non-bookmarkable way), you can just instantiate your page class like this:

```
setResponsePage( new ListContacts( param1, param2...) );
```

(Note that parameters don't need to be strings here, type safety is one of the great advantages of Wicket.)

Word of advice, It is vitally important to understand [the difference between bookmarkable and non-bookmarkable pages](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Bookmarkable+pages+and+links) in Wicket.

Comment: @Sebas Yeah, they moved their Wiki pages in the meantime. Updated the link to point to the new location.